# innerHTML generated content shows in Chrome but not in Firefox or Edge

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, cross-browser, innerhtml

the timeWorkedTotal.innerHTML content generated by JS shows up in Chrome but is empty in Firefox (and Edge). All other .innerHTML content shows without problem in either browser. If possible, I would like to resolve this using vanilla JS/html/css without using any libraries unless it is completely unavoidable.

I have tried to change innerHTML to alternatives like innerText and textContent but it did not help. I have checked the cross browser compatibility at https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html/ and it seems that innerHTML should work fine (I am not concerned with security at this point since picked up data is hard-coded).

```
let jobData = [
    {
        dateStart: "June 2016",
        dateEnd: "October 2018",
        dates: "June 2016 – October 2018",
        employer: "Tim Hortons",
        title: "Cashier"
    },
    {
        dateStart: "January 2013",
        dateEnd: "March 2017",
        dates: "January 2013 – March 2017",
        employer: "Café Bar Main Street",
        title: "Server"
    },
    {
        dateStart: "June 2015",
        dateEnd: "May 2017",
        dates: "June 2015 – May 2017",
        employer: "Café Bar Main Street",
        title: "Server"
    },
]
```

//A function that calculates the total time work at a job using collected start and end dates

```
for (let i = 0; i <= jobData.length - 1; i++) {
function daysBetween(jobData){
    let one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    start = new Date(jobData.dateStart).getTime();
    end = new Date(jobData.dateEnd).getTime();
    timeWorked = (end - start);
    let timeWorkedYears = (timeWorked / one_day /365).toFixed(2);

    let expDetails = document.getElementById('exp_details');
    let timeWorked2 = document.createElement('div');
    let timeWorkedTotal = document.createElement('span');
    expDetails.appendChild(timeWorked2);
    timeWorked2.appendChild(timeWorkedTotal);
    timeWorked2.classList.add('time_worked');
    timeWorkedTotal.classList.add('time_worked_total');

    //condition checks the length of employment and assigns proper "year/years"

          if(timeWorkedYears < 1.00) {
         timeWorkedTotal.innerHTML = ("less than a year") 
     } else if (timeWorkedYears == 1.00) {
        timeWorkedTotal.innerHTML = (Math.round(timeWorkedYears) + " year")
     } else if(timeWorkedYears > 1.00 && timeWorkedYears < 2.00) {
        timeWorkedTotal.innerHTML = (Math.round(timeWorkedYears) + "+ year")
     } else if(timeWorkedYears >= 2) {
        timeWorkedTotal.innerHTML = (Math.round(timeWorkedYears) + "+ years")
    }
}}
```

//Function that creates html elements for and display user input data related to work experience information

```
 for (let i = 0; i <= jobData.length - 1; i++) {
    experienceData(jobData[i]);
    daysBetween(jobData[i]);

function experienceData(jobData) {
    let expDetails = document.getElementById('exp_details');
    // empty div is created below that will hold all the of the data for job history
    let jobDiv = document.createElement('div');
    // new div is appended to the existing parent div
    expDetails.appendChild(jobDiv);
    // children of the jobDiv are created to hold dates, employer name and job title
    let jobDates = document.createElement('span');
    let employer = document.createElement('span');
    let title = document.createElement('span');
    // all children are appended to their respective parents
    jobDiv.appendChild(jobDates);
    jobDiv.appendChild(employer);
    jobDiv.appendChild(title);
    //class names are added to newly created elements in order to apply styling to them
    jobDiv.classList.add('job_parent');
    jobDates.classList.add('job_dates');
    employer.classList.add('employer');
    title.classList.add('job_title');
    //empty elements pick up information from the provided data file
    jobDates.innerHTML = jobData.dates;
    employer.innerHTML = jobData.employer;
    title.innerHTML = jobData.title;
}}
```

The innerHTML from the if else if statement for timeWorkedTotal does not show in the firefox although empty parent div and a holding span are generated with no problem.

Comment: `jobData.dateStart` is `"June 2016"` you then `new Date("June 2016")` which will fail as the input is not valid, the subsequent `getTime()` returns `NaN` which poisons all the related math and causes none of your if/else to match.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and
>   Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to
>   browser differences and inconsistencies.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

If the structure of dateStart and dateEnd is fix, you could use a litte function to convert the Strings in proper Date-Objects.

```
  // convert the date strings into Date-Objects  
  function convertDateStr(s) {
    var m = ['JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY', 'MARCH', 'APRIL', 'MAY', 'JUNE', 'JULY', 'AUGUST', 'SEPTEMBER', 'OCTOBER', 'NOVEMBER', 'DECEMBER'];
    var sArr = s.split(' ');
    return new Date(sArr[1],m.indexOf(sArr[0])).getTime();
  }
```

and use that in your function daysBetween

```
start = convertDateStr(jobData.dateStart);
end = convertDateStr(jobData.dateEnd);
```

```js
let jobData = [
  {
    dateStart: "June 2016",
    dateEnd: "October 2018",
    dates: "June 2016 – October 2018",
    employer: "Tim Hortons",
    title: "Cashier"
  },
  {
    dateStart: "January 2013",
    dateEnd: "March 2017",
    dates: "January 2013 – March 2017",
    employer: "Café Bar Main Street",
    title: "Server"
  },
  {
    dateStart: "June 2015",
    dateEnd: "May 2017",
    dates: "June 2015 – May 2017",
    employer: "Café Bar Main Street",
    title: "Server"
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i <= jobData.length - 1; i++) {
  function daysBetween(jobData){
    let one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    start = convertDateStr(jobData.dateStart);
    end = convertDateStr(jobData.dateEnd);
    timeWorked = (end - start);
    let timeWorkedYears = (timeWorked / one_day /365).toFixed(2);

    let expDetails = document.getElementById('exp_details');
    let timeWorked2 = document.createElement('div');
    let timeWorkedTotal = document.createElement('span');
    expDetails.appendChild(timeWorked2);
    timeWorked2.appendChild(timeWorkedTotal);
    timeWorked2.classList.add('time_worked');
    timeWorkedTotal.classList.add('time_worked_total');

    //condition checks the length of employment and assigns proper "year/years"

    if(timeWorkedYears < 1.00) {
      timeWorkedTotal.innerHTML = ("less than a year"); 
     } else if (timeWorkedYears == 1.00) {
        timeWorkedTotal.innerHTML = (Math.round(timeWorkedYears) + " year");
     } else if(timeWorkedYears > 1.00 && timeWorkedYears < 2.00) {
        timeWorkedTotal.innerHTML = (Math.round(timeWorkedYears) + "+ year");
     } else if(timeWorkedYears >= 2) {
        timeWorkedTotal.innerHTML = (Math.round(timeWorkedYears) + "+ years");
    }
  }
  // convert the date strings into Date-Objects  
  function convertDateStr(s) {
    var m = ['JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY', 'MARCH', 'APRIL', 'MAY', 'JUNE', 'JULY', 'AUGUST', 'SEPTEMBER', 'OCTOBER', 'NOVEMBER', 'DECEMBER'];
    var sArr = s.split(' ');
    return new Date(sArr[1],m.indexOf(sArr[0])).getTime();
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i <= jobData.length - 1; i++) {
    experienceData(jobData[i]);
    daysBetween(jobData[i]);
}
function experienceData(jobData) {
  let expDetails = document.getElementById('exp_details');
  // empty div is created below that will hold all the of the data for job history
  let jobDiv = document.createElement('div');
  // new div is appended to the existing parent div
  expDetails.appendChild(jobDiv);
  // children of the jobDiv are created to hold dates, employer name and job title
  let jobDates = document.createElement('span');
  let employer = document.createElement('span');
  let title = document.createElement('span');
  // all children are appended to their respective parents
  jobDiv.appendChild(jobDates);
  jobDiv.appendChild(employer);
  jobDiv.appendChild(title);
  //class names are added to newly created elements in order to apply styling to them
  jobDiv.classList.add('job_parent');
  jobDates.classList.add('job_dates');
  employer.classList.add('employer');
  title.classList.add('job_title');
  //empty elements pick up information from the provided data file
  jobDates.innerHTML = jobData.dates;
  employer.innerHTML = jobData.employer;
  title.innerHTML = jobData.title;
}
```

```html
<div id="exp_details"></div>
```